# How to make image go below text for mobile

Tags: css, responsive

How do I make the image go under the text in the mobile? And for the text to go on the left side, instead of being more on the right - if this makes sense :)

**CSS (Image):** https://pastebin.com/pGBdbBhs

**CSS (Content):** https://pastebin.com/1SY2JXUa

**HTML:**

```
<div class="content">
  <div class="left-200">
    <div>
      <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
      <div class="padding-4"></div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius, natus pariatur aut soluta sed consectetur deleniti tempore ducimus at quas officia, deserunt eaque magni!</p>
     </div>
    
     <div class="padding-10"></div>
     <img src="./images/default-image.png" alt="Image" class="image"/>
   </div>
 </div>
```

**Desktop:**

[image: Desktop1]

**Mobile:**

[image: Mobile]

Thank you!

Comment: You could either try flexbox or reassign values with @media queries.

Comment: @pso any ideas on how would I do that though? Sorry..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it! Basically I wrapped it up in a `div` and set `display:none;` if the device was on mobile. And I did the same thing for desktop!

Answer (score 0):

To make a responsive design you can either go the bootstrap root or you can do the @media in the CSS. Take a look at this site which will point you in the right direction.

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Comment: Ah, okay! I got the text to look way better! Except the image is still on the right, and on mobile, you can only see a bit of the image. How do I fix this? @MrJnrDev

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS and HTML looks a little random here and there. For example those padding divs. Also your .left-200 class has two display properties. I would recommend to clean it up and then add the paddings, margins etc.

You really only need `display: flex` and `flex-wrap` for this task and set the other values like width accordingly.

```
.content {
    padding: 200px 50px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
#flex-text {
    width: 400px;
}
```

```
<div class="content">
        <div id="flex-text">
            <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
            p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. <!--
                -->Eius, natus pariatur aut soluta sed consectetur deleniti tempore ducimus at quas officia, deserunt eaque magni!</p>
        </div>
        <div id="flex-image"> <img  src="./images/default-image.png" alt="Image" class="image"/> </div>
    </div>
```